# in aiml make a chatbot have a response to the amount of time i stayed logged out

Tags: aiml

how would I make a chatbot not answer my questions and play games with me if I do not log in for a week in aiml?how would I make it say I guess I can forgive you if I entered a sentence five times in aiml?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the time you ask each question in a variable, and then when answering each question check the time difference.

If you want to count the number of questions then again store it in a variable and use a condition based on the value to create the answer

Comment: how would I do that aiml?i need to know how to do it for my chatbot.